# KnockOutJs Visible Two-Way?

Tags: knockout.js

My presumption is that the KnockOutJs "visible" binding is two-way, so if I hide an dom element bound to a viewmodel property, a subscription to the observable would update. My sample in JsBin http://jsfiddle.net/zb6E9/20/ shows that if the observable is changed the subscription fires but if the dom element changes, the subscription does not fire.

I must be missing something, but what to do to make the jQuery button fire the subscription?

Html:

```
<input id="firstNameInput" data-bind="value: firstName, visible: isVisible" value="First" /><br />
<input data-bind="value: lastName" value="Last" /><br />
The name is <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span><br />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: changeVisibility" value="Change Visibility using KnockOut" /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="changeVisibilityJQuery()" value="Change Visibility Using jQuery" />
```

Javascript:

```
function changeVisibilityJQuery()
{
       if($('#firstNameInput').is(':visible')){
           $('#firstNameInput').hide();
       } else {
            $('#firstNameInput').show();
       }
 }

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('First');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('Last');
    self.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
    self.changeVisibility = function(){
        var  v = self.isVisible() || false;
        self.isVisible(!v);
    };
    self.isVisible.subscribe(function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
           // DO SOMETHING SUCH AS 
            self.firstName(self.firstName() + " " + bool);
        }
    });
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: No, the `visible` binding is only **one-way**: The visible binding causes the associated DOM element to become hidden or visible according to the value you pass to the binding.

Comment: So this is different from other knockoutjs observable properties such as text where updating the dom updates the model?

Comment: Yes, most of the bindings are one-way only a few of them two-way like the `value` or the `hasFocus` it is always described in the documentation how is a given binding works.

Comment: Is there a way to bind to a change in visibility if the dom element is manipulated outside of knockoutjs?

Comment: How would Knockout know that the visibility changed? There is no `changedVisibility` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as Michael Best has pointed out, there's no way for Knockout to detect an arbitrary visible change caused by outside code, the key is to make any code that has to change visibility do it by setting an `observable` used in a `visible` binding (so Knockout knows what's going on) rather than by manipulating the DOM directly. It's almost always best to let Knockout do all the DOM manipulation, either natively or through custom bindings. One of the most important points of MV* is that you have a single authority for updating views rather than a free-for-all.

Comment: Not sure I agree about everything having to go through the MV* model for cross-cutting concerns. There can be approaches that are not a free-for-all. In this case the control would be in site-wide accordian control that is working well and would not want to change with more specific logic, but I get your point.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was obviously mistaken about the 2-way binding being for visible etc. I do think the Knockout documentation could be a little more obvious about this... (One of these days) I will have to figure out a KO custom binding handler to make this work.